# Why won't Jquery/javascript to work on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a website and I need to use javascript/jquery on it. I was trying to use it on a scroll to top button and it wouldn't work. So then I tried it on a simple alert("..."); and it still wouldn't work. So I am wondering if the jquery or something isn't loading properly. I tried also tried putting the alert("..."); in my html file and found that it worked there but I need it to work in my .js file. Also this might help but in my .js file all my $ are underlined red and it says "cannot find name '$' any". Please please heeelp! :)

This is main html, it doesn't have much content as that will appear in other html files to create different pages. Sorry if the code isn't laid out too nicely, this is my first time using stack overflow aha. (I am also using Visual Studio Code on a mac if thats relevant in the matter)

MY HTML:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Web Tutorials</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="TutorialSiteCSSv1.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="siteJScript.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="banner">
<h1>Website Design and Construction Basic Tutorials</h1>
</div>

<div id="menunav">
<ul >
<li><a href="TutorialSitev1.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="StructuringPage.html">Structuring</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="StructuringPage.html#divs">Divs</a></li>
        <li><a href="StructuringPage.html#paragraphs">Paragraphs</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#html5">HTML5</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#whatsHTML5">What's HTML5?</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#css">CSS</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#whatsCSS">What's CSS?</a></li>
<li><a href="#cssText">CSS Text</a></li>
<li><a href="#cssMedia">CSS Media</a></li>
<li><a href="#cssPositioning">CSS Positioning</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div id="webIntro">
<h2>Home</h2>

<p> content.....
</p> 

<p> 
content....
</p>

</div>

<a href="#" class="scrollToTop"></a>

</body>

</html>
```

MY JS file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(document).ready(function(){
alert("jQuery is working!");
});
});
```

I also have a css file but didn't think that was relevant to the issue. I would have thought that the alert would be displayed but it isn't. I really need some help with this so it would be so so much appreciated if you could since I've got a deadline, thank you :)

this is the new JS I have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//if window is not at the top then display the button
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if($(this).scrollTop()>100) {
        $('.scrollToTop').fadeIn();
    }
    else{
        $('.scollToTop').fadeOut();
    }
});

//scrolls to top when clicked
    $('.scrollToTop').click(function() {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop:0}, 800);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, *is* jquery loading properly? Have you checked your browser to see if the file is being downloaded properly?

Comment: is the path correct to your script file? easy to check in browser dev tools if it is loading or not

Comment: @JonathanM that doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I was thinking maybe it had something to do with a library missing or something but i wouldn't know what to look for or how to check

Comment: could you put the page up in a publicly accessible place so we can see it?

Comment: jQuery path is correct...hit f12 on browser and look for network tab..will see all resources in page..and their status. Look for your script file

Comment: it says it failed to load resource, but I definitely have the name siteJScript.js right

Comment: What failed to load as a resource YOUR javascript or jquery? And *why* did it fail to load? What's the (network) error code?

Comment: name might be right...but directory path is probably not

Comment: pressing f12 on the mac just changes volume for my :/ sorry to be awkward

Comment: sounds like you put the file in a different directory than the page. path is relative to that page

Comment: Ah yeah, I just reread your post. I thought you said moving the alert *did* fix the problem. Yeah, you don't have the JS file in the same page as your HTML.

Comment: thanks guys a managed to get the alert to show by changing it to .js not .min.js ! But now I can't get the scroll function to work how I would like to. If I add in the code can you guys see if you can help me out with that too, thanks you :)

Comment: don't add to this question..it;s already a mess, start a new one focused on new issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any obvious issues with your code. I tried to run your code locally on a http server and got the alert. So I would look at the javascript file path and make sure that you have that added correctly in your html file.

Another thing you can do to debug the issue is open the html page in chrome (or firefox if you prefer) and try to see if you get any errors in the console by opening the developer tools.

If there are any issues with the script they may be reported on the console.

TIP: you can open the console by pressing F12 or (Ctrl + Shift + I).

You do have two $.ready functions nested within each other but that should not running your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

from what I can see your code looks correct. Try opening a web debugger tools (f12 in chrome) and seeing if there are any errors. Also if you look at the network tab and refresh the page to see all the requests it will tell you if your pages were loaded. This would tell you if your jquery link wasn't working or if your path to your JavaScript was wrong. I would guess it is one of these issues because that would lead to the $ not being found from the jquery library (ie one or both or your jquery is files aren't being included) hope this helps.